# How to add or remove /mnt/c/ in WSL 2 with Pengwin and zsh

Tags: zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pengwin

I have two Windows machines with WSL 2/Pengwin/zsh here and the first one shows prompt and refers to files and folders in Windows as `/c/...` but the second as `/mnt/c/...` for one and the same folder or file in Windows. I'm not sure which one I like better yet but surely I'd like to be able to switch between the two modes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pengwin-setup made the change from /mnt/c to /c when you installed docker. This change is located in this file: `/etc/wsl.conf`

```
[automount]
**root=/**
enabled = true
options = "metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,fmask=11,case=off"
mountFsTab = true
crossDistro = true
```

Change `root=/mnt` to change to the default behavior or simply delete the **root** line.

Restart Windows to apply the change

Answer (score 1):

By accident, I ran into a (the?) solution for Pengwin:

1. Make sure you have installed Docker Desktop
2. In pengwin-setup install the Docker bridge to Docker Desktop

I hope this is not the only solution and there would be a better way not dependant on Docker. Anyone?